# How to re-install kde splash screen with tty1

Tags: installation, kubuntu, desktop-environments

I accidentally uninstalled the splash screen I was using in Kubuntu 11.10 and now it takes me to tty. Can any body tell me how to re-install the kde splash screen so I can login and use my computer again? (I was using the default theme which is "horos" but it doesn't matter what theme is re-installed as long as it works.)

Comment: `sudo aptitude reinstall -f kubuntu-desktop`

Comment: @Achu Didn't work... It said "sudo: aptitude: location not found" or something along those lines...

Comment: replace with `apt-get`

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[Achu](https://askubuntu.com/users/9701) gave the answer in the comment:

```
sudo aptitude reinstall -f kubuntu-desktop
```

And if `aptitude` not works you can use:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall -f kubuntu-desktop
```

Before you can enter those commands you need to login first. Enter your username, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and enter your password followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Now you get a prompt where you can insert the command.